# Heroku/Ecto/Postgres 28000 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "115.159.183.134", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Tags: postgresql, heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

While there have been similar posts, none seems to match this situation so thank you for reading.  On our production application (Heroku/Elixir/Phoenix/Ecto/Postgres), I am seeing thousands of errors of the form:

```
[IVORY] [10-1] sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "181.1.249.94", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

While such errors are commonly diagnosed as an issue with the pga_hba.conf file, in this case I believe the issue is an non-SSL attempt to read/write from the database, though I have no idea why that would be occurring with the following configuration:

```
config :app_name, AppName.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"),
  ssl: true,
  pool_size: 5
```

With SSL as true, I don't know why any non-SSL DB read/writes would be attempted.  If it's something outside of Ecto, I don't know what it would be.  Each attempt is coming from a unique IP, it seems, which seems unusual to me.   I am trying to figure out what steps to take to track down what's going on, so any advice is highly welcome.

phoenix_ecto: "3.3.0"
postgrex: 0.13.5
Postgres: 10.2
Heroku Buildpack: https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir.git

The most mystifying aspect of this issue is that there are handful of such errors in the log reports over the past couple months and then out of the blue we've had thousands of errors of this kind in the last few days.

Comment: it's an untargetted attack to postgres DBs hosted on Horeku https://security.stackexchange.com/a/204724

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense, thanks for filling me in.